# My inertia app does not detect some specific colors from Tailwind (Laravel Vue inertia tailwind)

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

My app does not detect some colors of the Tailwind palette.

In this case, `text-green-500` called `primaryColorGreen` and `text-indigo-600` called `secondaryColor` are working properly.

However, `text-red-300` as `primaryColorRed` is not working, but it does work if I change `text-red-300` to `text-red-600.

If I change `text-green-500` for `text-green-300` it doesn't work.

The same for the indigo color...in general only some colors are working.

**Layout.js:**

```js
export const useLayoutStore = defineStore('layout', {
    state: () => (
        {
            navigation: [],
            currentModels: [],
            currentRoute: 'x',
            theme: {
                classes: {
                    primaryColorGreen: 'text-green-500',
                },
            },
            color: {
                primary: {
                    primaryColorRed: 'text-red-300',
                }
            },
            textColor: {
                secondary: {
                    secondaryColor: 'text-indigo-600',
                }
            }
        }
    ),
});
```

**HandleInertiaRequest.php:**

```php
            'theme'=>[
                'classes'=>[
                    'primaryColorGreen' => 'text-green-500',
                ],
            ],
            'color' => [
                'primary' => [
                    'primaryColorRed' => 'text-red-300',
                ]
            ],
            'textColor' => [
                'secondary' => [
                    'secondaryColor' => 'text-indigo-600',
                ]
            ],
```

**Vue page:**

```js
<script setup>
import {useLayoutStore} from '@/Stores/layout';


const theme = useLayoutStore().theme //
const color = useLayoutStore().color
const textColor = useLayoutStore().textColor
</script>

<template>

<h2 class="mx-auto max-w-2xl text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight">

<span:class="theme.classes.primaryColorGreen">hello</span> 
<span:class="color.primary.primaryColorRed">how are you</span>
<span :class="textColor.secondary.secondaryColor"> Raul</span>

</h2>
```

Comment: Perhaps you tweaked the color opacities array and `text-*-300` is no longer generated for any color?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following values to the content array in the tailwaind.config.js file.

```
content:[
    ......
    './resources/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './resources/*/.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Jetstream with Intertia stack, then the location of your file containing Tailwind classes are probably aren't scanned by tailwind. which normally scan `php` and `vue` files inside `resources` directory

check the `tailwind.config.js` and add those files which contains tailwind css classes.

or move those files to somewhere that are scan by tailwind default config