# Laravel + InertiaJs + vite + tailwind failing to render specific colors

Tags: vite, inertiajs, laravel-10, tailwind-3

This is (almost) a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374369/my-inertia-app-does-not-detect-some-specific-colors-from-tailwind-laravel-vue-i) question, but because I don't have enough reputation to comment on questions, I thought I'd raise it again.

Stack: Laravel 10, Inertia 1, Vite 4, Tailwind 3

The CSS is being faithfully rendered in the most of the application of blade and Inertia files. The problem started yesterday with a custom color, but that *seemed* to self-resolve after I left my desk for a walk. Today, after several hours of coding the same project without this problem rearing its head, it has returned, this time, however, with standard tailwind colors slate-700 and darker. Today, slate-600 and lighter render correctly, as do the customer colors that were problematic yesterday.

**vite.config.js:**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                base: null,
                includeAbsolute: false
            }
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.es.js'),
        },
    },
});
```

**tailwind.config.js (excerpt):**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/js/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
}
```

**app.js:**

```
import './bootstrap';
import './main';

import { ZiggyVue } from 'ziggy'
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers"
import '../css/app.css'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: (name) =>
    resolvePageComponent(
      `./Pages/${name}.vue`,
      import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue")
    ),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .use(ZiggyVue)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

**Example html/css:**

```
<input multiple id="postImage" type="file" class="w-full text-slate-500 text-sm tracking-tight font-medium bg-lmhlBgInput shadow-sm rounded-lg focus:outline-1 focus:outline-lmhlMain1 border border-slate-400 focus:shadow-md file:bg-transparent file:border-0 file:bg-slate-600 file:mr-4 file:py-4 file:px-4 file:text-slate-400 file:cursor-pointer">
```

Note the file:bg-slate-600: At darkness of -700 and darker this instruction is ignored, though maybe not tomorrow or after a long break. It is as if there is a tangle-up somehow in memory, some kind of cancelling-out, that expires by accident after some length of time, but can happen again at some point, apparently randomly. Otherwise, i.e. for other elements, slate-700 and darker render correctly.

[image: slate-600 for input element, slate-700 for button]
slate-600 for input element, slate-700 for button

[image: slate-700 for input element, slate-700 for button]
slate-700 for input element, slate-700 for button

No error messages to be seen anywhere.

I do not know which software component in the mix is responsible.

I have tried rejigging how css is mixed by vite, with no changes in behaviour. I have also tried far simpler test pages to isolate the problem, but it seems random. I am expecting all available CSS colors, custom and tailwind standard, to be correctly rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind purges unused css, in the other question you linked the user tried to apply styles over the HandleInertiaRequest. Why some classes worked and other's didnt was probably because the old style was still in the tailwind generated css file.

The default tailwind config you find everywhere doesnt scan php files for class names. Thus these are never included in the build and weird stuff can happen, where you think it's working but only because the style is already included because of some other element.

Similar things can happen when you try to use a tailwind class using string concatenation. I.e.

```js
const styles = () => {
    return "bg-" + (true ? "black" : "white");
};
```

hover this magically works, if you already use `bg-white` and `bg-black` somewhere else, because the style class is already included.

If you are sure you dont do this then I would check how the generated css file looks like.